# Program to remove special characters non ascii from large texfiles

Tags: windows, text-editor, text-processing

I have text files 100MB+ in size and they have a lot of special chars. I can't import them into my DBMS because PostgreSql doesn't recognize these chars. 
How can I remove them? Which software does this?

I am currently using EmEditor but I have to find special chars manually and replace all. There's tons of them. Over 10k. I'm on Windows.

Comment: Do you have access to a Linux machine? It would be a single command line on Linux, if you can boot it for example with a Live CD

Answer (score 1):

A very simple [python](https://www.python.org/) script, *or even from a terminal/command line interactive session*, could read from an input file and write to an output file while changing the encoding to ASCII - you would have a choice of what to do about the nonconforming characters of:

- ignore *skip none ascii characters*
- replace *with `?`*
- xmlcharrefreplace *output in a format like `&#40960;`*
- backslashreplace *output in a format like `\\ua000`*
- namereplace *output in a format like `\\N{YI SYLLABLE IT}` where names are available.*

The code, in Python 3 would be something like, *untested*:

```
with open('somefilename') as infile: # You may need to add 'rb' to the open command
   with open('outname', 'wt') as outfile:  # You may need to use 'wb' here
      outfile.write(infile.read().encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace'))
```

The above code will read the input file transcode it and write it out - you could also, for large file specify a maximum buffer size in the `read` method.

See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html for more details.

Python is free, gratis & open source, and available for just about every platform, *it is pre-installed on most non-Windows platforms*.

Answer (score 1):

Install **CudaText** editor.

- Call menuitem "Plugins - Make Plugin"
- Enter plugin name "MyRemove", and enter new plugin text, below.
- Save, restart CudaText, new plugin appears "Plugins - MyRemove".
- Open your file with non-ASCII
- Run plugin
- Save file as...

Plugin text:

```
from cudatext import *

class Command:
    def run(self):
        s=ed.get_text_all()
        for i in range(32):
            if not i in [10,13,9]:
                s=s.replace(chr(i), '')
        ed.set_text_all(s)
```